# Porting JWT stateless authentication from Nancy 1.4.5 to 2.0.0

Tags: authentication, jwt, nancy

I implemented JWT stateless authentication in Nancy 1.4.5 and it used to work fine.
Porting my project to Nancy 2.0.0, the authentication mechanism doesn't work any more.

In the bootstrapper's ApplicationStartup method I have:

```
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(IKernel container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        #region JWT authentication
        // JWT stateless authentication, see: https://foreverframe.net/nancy-meets-jwt-authentication/
        var secretKey = LocalConstants.Authorization.SecretKey;
        string cryptografyAlgorithm = LocalConstants.Authorization.CryptografyAlgorithm;
        string bearerDeclaration = LocalConstants.Authorization.HttpHeaderBearerDeclaration;
        var identityProvider = new IdentityProvider(secretKey, cryptografyAlgorithm, bearerDeclaration);
        var statelessAuthConfig = new StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration(identityProvider.GetUserIdentity);
        StatelessAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, statelessAuthConfig);
        #endregion
        ...
```

At run-time, clients can perform login and correctly get the JWT. They store the JWT in an HTTP header in subsequent requests. When subsequent requests reach the server, my identityProvider's GetUserIdentity method reads the JWT and correctly returns a valid ClaimsPrincipals.

In my module's

```
 this.RequiresAuthentication();
```

, though, a Nancy.ErrorHandling.RouteExecutionEarlyExitException is thrown with reason "Requires Authentication", reason "Requires Authentication" and a response "Unauthorized text/html" with status code Nancy.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.

What is the correct way to port the stateless authentication to Nancy 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself: problem is not in the configuration, but in the way the JWT is used in the server. The function passed as argument to the StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration object (identityProvider.GetUserIdentity in my example) should return a ClaimsIdentity whose identity is authenticated.

To do that, pass a non-null, non-empty string as authenticationType parameter, like here:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CustomAuthenticationType");
```

In my previous attempt, I just passed the claims, causing claimsIdentity to have its IsAuthenticated property evaluating to False.